# Django | Factory boy | faking a boolean field | django.db.utils.DataError: value too long for type character varying(1)

Tags: django, factory-boy

I am trying to use factory boy to generate fake entries but I'm stepping on an issue related with the boolean field.

Follows the Model and ModelFactory:

```py
# models.py

class Record(models.Model):
    date_creation = models.DateTimeField()
    rec_type = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=RECORD_TYPES)
    direction = models.BooleanField()
```

```py
# factories.py

class RecordFactory(DjangoModelFactory):

    class Meta:
        model = Record

    date_creation = factory.Faker('date_time')
    rec_type = factory.Faker('random_choices', elements=[x[1] for x in Record.RECORD_TYPES])
    direction = factory.Faker('pybool')
```

How do I fix this issue? Seems to be related with the boolean field.

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py:1427: RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField Record.date_creation received a naive datetime (1
977-11-24 14:21:26) while time zone support is active.
  RuntimeWarning)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.errors.StringDataRightTruncation: value too long for type character varying(1)


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 30, in <module>   
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 364, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options) 
File "/app/iur/core/management/commands/seed.py", line 60, in handle
    self.create(options["records"], RecordFactory)
  File "/app/iur/core/management/commands/seed.py", line 47, in create
    factory_class.create()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/factory/base.py", line 564, in create
    return cls._generate(enums.CREATE_STRATEGY, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/factory/django.py", line 141, in _generate
    return super(DjangoModelFactory, cls)._generate(strategy, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/factory/base.py", line 501, in _generate
    return step.build()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/factory/builder.py", line 279, in build
    kwargs=kwargs,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/factory/base.py", line 315, in instantiate
    return self.factory._create(model, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/factory/django.py", line 185, in _create
    return manager.create(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 422, in create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 741, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 779, in save_base
    force_update, using, update_fields,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 870, in _save_table
    result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 908, in _do_insert
    using=using, raw=raw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1186, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1335, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 99, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 67, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 76, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.DataError: value too long for type character varying(1)
```

Comment: It's might not be the boolean field that fails but `rec_type = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=RECORD_TYPES)`
as it's max_length is 1. Can you confirm that `RECORD_TYPES` are max 1 character?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The major issue was that I was using the wrong Faker. This one did what I expected:

```py
# factories.py

...

rec_type = factory.Faker('random_element', elements=[x[0] for x in Record.RECORD_TYPES])

...
```

Answer (score 2):

It might not be the boolean field that cause the error but

```py
rec_type = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=RECORD_TYPES)
```

As it's max_length is 1. Can you confirm that RECORD_TYPES are max 1 character?

> django.db.utils.DataError: value too long for type character varying(1)

This should indicate that it's a VARCHAR of max length 1. And from what I can see from the trace, you're db backend is postgres where there is a native boolean field.

Answer (score 1):

Just set e.g. `direction = False` in `RecordFactory`. Or, if you want to use `faker`, you can do `direction = Faker().pybool()`

I think the error is telling you that your DB backend uses a one letter varchar for representing booleans (most probably `"t"` and `"f"`).

Comment: > "Or, if you want to use faker, you can do `direction = factory.Faker().pybool()`", did you mean `direction = fake.pybool()`? If that's what you meant, how is that different? The output object is still a `bool` type object, not a "t" nor "f". (Genuine question)

Comment: I did my testing directly with Faker so it's possible factoryboy usage is different (I don't know what is `fake`). Django' ORM will take care of properly storing the bool value in DB.

Comment: By `fake` I mean `fake = Faker()`. I should have been more explicit. So the question should have been: did you mean `direction = Faker().pybool()`?